# Why isn't Mac's Trash search scoped to the Trash by default?

Tags: search, search-results, mac-os-x

When I open the Trash on Mac, it's usually because I'm looking for a specific file that I deleted.

I'll search for the file name (or part of it)... and then the Mac returns every file in the file system that matches, by default, on "This Mac". I have to click Trash in order to find the file in the Trash, every time.

[image: Searching This Mac]

What's the UX reason that search isn't scoped to the Trash by default, when there's already an easy-to-access global search (command-F)? Doesn't this violate the User Control heuristic?

Comment: Who is it that you expect will be able to answer this question on here?

Comment: Folks with deep domain knowledge around search.

Comment: Is this a pattern that has been constant throughout the different OS versions? Or something introduced in recent updates? Unless there's someone working over at Apple who can help us, I think we'll probably be all left scratching our heads on this one.

Comment: I seem to remember it starting when OSX first rolled out, so, it's been around a very long time.

Comment: Unfortunately, only members of the Apple design team can answer this question with any degree of certainty. Any other answers will just be speculation which we don't do here.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually change this behavior in the Finder preferences.
[image: MacOS Finder preferences]